# Determine longitudes and latitudes within a range

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have locations in my database. A location has the attributes latitude and longitude (taken from google maps, example: 48.809591).
Is there any query that could help me retrieve the locations within a range of another location?

Example:
I have the location A with latitude = 48.809591, and longitude = 2.124009 and want to retrieve all location objects in my database that are within 5 miles of location A

My first thought was to retrieve the locations in a square where location.latitude < A.latitude + 5 miles and location.latitude > A.latitude - 5 miles and location.longitude < A.longitude + 5 miles and location.longitude > A.longitude - 5 miles, and then remove the irrelevant locations from the returned array with the help of something like http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Any ideas?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: how important is it that the locations are exactly in the 5 mile radius? (for instance does it matter that they are in the 'corners' or the square?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you're using MySQL as your DBMS<sup>1</sup>, you may be interested in checking out the following presentation:

- [Geo/Spatial Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)<sup>2</sup> by [Alexander Rubin](http://www.arubin.org/blog/presentations/)

The author describes how you can use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in MySQL to order spatial data by proximity and limit the results to a defined radius. More importantly, he also describes how to avoid a full table scan for such queries, using traditional indexes on the latitude and longitude columns.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even if you aren't, this is still interesting and applicable.
<sup>2</sup> There is also a [pdf version](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf) of the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation you want, i think, is called the great circle distance:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Answer (score 0):

You would need a distance function.

For [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) it would look something like this (note that distance is in kilometers),

```
    CREATE FUNCTION distance
    (
      @startLatitude float, 
      @startLongitude float, 
      @endLatitude float,
      @endLongitude float
    )
    RETURNS float
    AS
    BEGIN

      DECLARE @distance float;

      set @distance = 
        6371 * 2 * atn2(sqrt(power(sin(pi() / 180 * (@endLatitude - @startLatitude) / 2), 2) +
        power(cos(@startLatitude * pi() / 180), 2) *
        power(sin(pi() / 180 * (@endLongitude - @startLongitude) / 2), 2)),
        sqrt(1 - power(sin(pi() / 180 * (@endLatitude - @startLatitude) / 2), 2) +
        power(cos(@startLatitude * pi() / 180), 2) *
        power(sin(pi() / 180 * (@endLongitude - @startLongitude) / 2), 2)));
      RETURN @distance
    END
```

Comment: Note that SQL Server 2008 has in-built geospatial capabilities, with a native distance function, and geo-spatial indexing. Using a UDF like the above would require a full table scan to order the results by distance.