# Getting near objects. Django + Badoo

Tags: python, django

I have the following situation.

I keep track of a user's longitude and latitude using ios.
I send the longitude and latitude coordinates to a django server.

How can I use these longitude and latitude coordinates to determine what objects are near?

Basically how can I use these coordinates to determine the list of other users near a user?

Comment: Do you use `GeoDjango`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your backend object has a lat and longitude, here's an useful snippet for making a proximity query:

```
objects = ObjectModel.objects.exclude(lat__isnull=True).exclude(lng__isnull=True).extra(
              where=["3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((%(lat)s - abs(lat)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(%(lat)s * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(lat) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((%(lng)s - lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) < 50" % {'lat': lat, 'lng': lng}],
          )
```

Similar question: [Determine longitudes and latitudes within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927258/determine-longitudes-and-latitudes-within-a-range)

Answer (score 0):

You keep track of all users, and you show all users whose coordinates are of a similar value.

Yes, that's a generic answer, but it is a very generic question.

I would not be surprised if there are modules for Django doing this already.

Comment: If the question is too generic you can always ask for clarifications. This does not constitute an answer. P.S. GeoDjango exists for years https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries

Comment: The question is not unclear. It's just very *wide*. If you don't think this is a real question, feel free to vote to close it.

Comment: It is a real question. It just misses important details for a comprehensive answer. You must have noticed that I have asked the OP a very specific question.

Comment: It misses *tons* of "details" for a comprehensive answer. I answered the question. If this isn't a real answer, then the question is not a real question.

Comment: We don't disagree on the question Lennart. You're an SO member for far longer than me and you do know what are the guidelines for a proper answer. 1 line for something that resembles an answer, 1 line for apologizing for the lack of a solution and 1 line for a speculation about a possible solution, does not a proper answer make. I don't want to drag this further than it has to. Maybe I made my point, maybe I didn't. Peace all around.