# Find latitude and longitude with in 2 miles radius from a given lat-long

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an table with latitude and longitude.

I need to find all latitude and longitude with in 2 miles radius from a given lat-long.

I am fetching data using jquery ajax using C# from sqlserver database.

I need this in sqlserver query.

For example:

If I give 37.774546 and -122.433523, than I need to get all lat-long from the list that 
are in 2 miles radius.

Comment: We'll need more information to help you out. Where exactly do you wish to do the filtering? In the database, in the C# layer, or in javascript?

Comment: How is your "question" related to the tags it has? This sounds more like a math problem.

Comment: you should ask to hitesh gupta.....

Comment: Sorry guys I have edited my question

Comment: Looks still rather a math problem to me ; ). Please take a look at [this page ...](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: Its same like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927258/determine-longitudes-and-latitudes-within-a-range) but I need it in javascript

Comment: There are several JS codes at the page I've linked.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on SQL 2008, you can take advantage of the native geospatial querying capabilities. For instance:

```
declare @distance_in_meters int = 2000;
declare @point geography = geography::Point( 37.774546, -122.433523, 4326 );
declare @buffer geography = @point.STBuffer( @distance_in_meters );

select * 
from dbo.yourtable
where @buffer.STContains( t.Point );
```

Note that dbo.yourtable.Point will have to have the geography datatype and the actual data will have to have the same SRID as the reference point. But it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query for Database:

```
Declare @Miles int=10;

Declare @Latitude varchar(15);  
Declare @Longitude varchar(15);  
Set @Latitude = 'set input lat here'
Set @Longitude = 'set input long here'

Select Round(((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(Latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(@Latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(@Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude - @Longitude))))) * 69.09),0) As Distance,
Latitude as lat, 
Longitude as longi     
From tablename                    
       Where @Miles > ((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(Latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(@Latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(@Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(Longitude - @Longitude))))) * 69.09)
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do it that way.

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng())
var x = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(ne, nw);
var y = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(sw, nw);
```